# Installing torchlight on Laravel 9 and getting cURL error 60

Tags: laravel, torchlight-laravel

I am tyring to install torchlight on laravel using these docs https://torchlight.dev/docs/clients/laravel

I have gotten to the blade component part

```
<x-torchlight-code language='php'>
    echo "Hello World!";
</x-torchlight-code>

<pre><x-torchlight-code language='php'>
    echo "Hello World!";
</x-torchlight-code></pre>
```

I am getting this error
https://flareapp.io/share/x7Xo6DxP#F34
[image]

I saw on a post that my guzzle might be outdated, and I tried to update it but doesn't seem to work still.

Any ideas on what else might be the issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue is resolved, I had to download this file https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem and put it in the `php/extra/ssl` folder

Then in the php.ini file to find the `curl.cainfo` and update the path

Now it all works :D